# How to parse a laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a laravel collection on output, I want to parse it ->toArray()

```
Collection {#335
  #items: array:2 [
    "0f39b1e0-a507-11e7-9d6e-33e84951047e" => array:2 [
      "total_amount" => 25000
      "debt_type" => array:2 [
        0 => "car_loan"
        1 => "car_loan"
      ]
    ]
    "0f218520-a507-11e7-b0ba-8554a4ad039b" => array:2 [
      "total_amount" => 15000
      "debt_type" => array:1 [
        0 => "house_loan"
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

is there any way to parse it so I get the following output:

```
    array:1[
      0=>[
       'debt_id'=>'0f39b1e0-a507-11e7-9d6e-33e84951047e',
       'debt_type'=>'car_loan',
       'total_amount'=>25000
      ],
      1=>[
       'debt_id'=>'0f218520-a507-11e7-b0ba-8554a4ad039b',
       'debt_type'=>'house_loan',
       'total_amount'=>15000
      ]
]
```

what I have tried it works but not sure if its a good way to go around it:

```
$appDebts = $appDebts->groupBy('debt_type_id')->map(function ($item) {
    return [

        'total_amount' => $item->sum('amount'),
        'debt_type'    => $item->map(function ($item) {
            return $item->debt_type->slug;
        })->toArray(),
    ];
})->toArray();
```

if you dd $appDebts you get the collection that I have added on top of the post

```
$carLoan     = [];
$studentLoan = [];
$houseLoan   = [];
$cardLoan    = [];

foreach ($appDebts as $debt) {

    if ($debt['debt_type'][0] === 'car_loan') {
        $carLoan['TotalAmount'] = $debt['total_amount'];
        $carLoan['LoanType']    = $debt['debt_type'][0];

    }
    if ($debt['debt_type'][0] === 'house_loan') {

        $houseLoan['TotalAmount'] = $debt['total_amount'];
        $houseLoan['LoanType']    = $debt['debt_type'][0];
    }
    if ($debt['debt_type'][0] === 'student_loan') {

        $studentLoan['TotalAmount'] = $debt['total_amount'];
        $studentLoan['LoanType']    = $debt['debt_type'][0];
    }
    if ($debt['debt_type'][0] === 'credit_card_loan') {

        $cardLoan['TotalAmount'] = $debt['total_amount'];
        $cardLoan['LoanType']    = $debt['debt_type'][0];
    }

}
```

Comment: have a look on [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-toarray)

Comment: Iterate through the collection and create your own array, since the structure you want does not match the collection's structure.

Comment: @JigarShah i already know that function thats why I mentioned on my question but the problem is how ?

Comment: @aynber I already did that but I don't quite like the code how it looks, thought maybe there is a way using laravel helpers for dealing with collections. My way wass I converted everything to array then foreach and build my own array.

Comment: @trace_le _I already did that_... Show us your code.

Comment: You don't need to convert to an array first, so that would remove one step. But as I said, the structure you want does not match the structure of the collection, so creating your own array in a foreach loop is really the only way I know of to do what you want.

Comment: You can try https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-each but honestly speaking, done is better than perfect, you are sort of wasting your time with perfecting this. Also easier solution could be improving SQL query instead perfecting PHP code.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yeah check out the edited post

Comment: @veNuker I am just eagerloading nested relationships trying to avoid N+1 problem. check the edited post for query builder see if you can give me some better tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this mapping after the first one that you did :

```
$appDebts = $appDebts->groupBy('debt_type_id')->map(function ($item) {
    return [

        'total_amount' => $item->sum('amount'),
        'debt_type'    => $item->map(function ($item) {
            return $item->debt_type->slug;
        })->toArray(),
    ];
}); // <-- remove ->toArray() from here 

$appDebts = $appDebts->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return [
        'debt_type_id' => $key
        'debt_type'    => $item["debt_type"][0], // assuming you want the first type !!
        'total_amount' => $item["total_amount"],
    ];
})->toArray();
```

PS : This convert the given collection to tha wanted array for more performance tweaking consider editing the SQL query or the logic of getting `appDebts`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the array you shared:

```
$parsed = $collection->map(function ($item, $id) {
    return [
        'debt_id' => $id,
        'debt_type' => collect($item['debt_type'])->first(),
        'total_amount' => $item['total_amount']
    ];
})->values()->toArray();
```

With `values` you remove the `key => value`, you get the array without keys

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can add to @Llopele's answer is to use `keyBy()` for easier data access:

```
$parsed = $collection->map(function ($item, $id) {
    return [
        'debt_id' => $id,
        'debt_type' => collect($item['debt_type'])->first(),
        'total_amount' => $item['total_amount']
    ];
})->values()->keyBy('debt_type')->toArray();
```

So now you can access data like this `Arr::get($parsed, 'house_loan');`